# POST Request com token

Tags: android, rest, post, http-post

1. Iniciar uma requisição HTTP via método POST para a URL de autenticação, com os seguintes parâmetros:

   - login
   - password

   response = http://api.dominio.com:8025/name/login?token="MY_TOKEN"
2. A resposta da requisição feita em 1 terá como resposta uma outra URL. Esta URL representa a localização da instância do sistema a que o usuário pertence, portanto, deve-se fazer uma nova requisição para a URL informada.

Alguém sabe como faço o passo 2? 
Estou usando Android Asynchronous Http Client

Um exemplo em Linux bash/shell script
[image: um exemplo em Linux bash/shell script]

Comment: Essa URL aí tem um parâmetro com formato de GET, é isso mesmo? O token não teria que ir junto do corpo do post?

Answer (score 5):

Veja se é mais ou menos isso (se o token tiver que ir dentro do post):

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.dominio.com:8025/name/login");

  try {
     List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();

     // Aqui setamos o token:
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", "ab124b3a1c2f"));
     // repita a linha de cima quantas vezes necessário,
     // com outras variaveis e parâmetros desejados.

     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     // trate dos erros aqui
  } catch (IOException e) {
     // e aqui
  }
```

> Notar que eu não postei o código usando *async*, coloquei a resposta apenas como uma referência inicial. Dependendo do caso, o *async* acaba até atrapalhando o fluxo quando se trata de requisições interdependentes, pois você tem que gerenciar os eventos no seu código.

**Edit**: talvez seja necessário usar desta forma, pondo a URL toda aqui:

```
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost( response );
```

e retirar o token do POST, deixando somente as outras variáveis necessárias, se houver:

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("variavel1", "valor1..."));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("variavel2", "valor2..."));
```

Comment: Não funcionou, sempre dá erro 404 not found

Comment: @IgorRonner vc testou num browser se o endereço está correto?

Comment: como? se ele não suporta GET

Comment: Provavelmente não vai ser um 404 se vc usar o método errado, mas sim outro erro. 404 geralmente é quando não existe o endereço mesmo. E pra testar o endereço com post no browser, basta criar uma página com um `<form action="http://api.dominio.com:8025/name/login" method="post">`

Comment: tá dando erro HTTP Status 401 - Invalid token android agora

Comment: @IgorRonner está dando o 401 no seu app ou no teste por browser? Se for no app, a mensagem é auto-explicativa. Se for no teste browser, é normal, visto que o token não está sendo passado.

Comment: em ambos os testes.

Comment: @Igor já melhorou então, se deu 401 significa que a URL está correta, a requisição está correta, e apenas o token está indo errado. Resta saber se o token tem que ir no POST ou como parte da URL, como você exemplificou inicialmente. Aí, é apenas a documentação da API que vai dizer. Pode ser que o token precise estar na URL, e apenas o resto das variáveis no POST. Faltam detalhes na pergunta sobre isso, então estou meio que "adivinhando" o que pode ser, passo a passo.

Comment: @Bacco, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda! 
Na documentação tem o seguinte 
Sendo que já passei pelo passo um

1.     Iniciar uma requisição HTTP via método POST para a URL de autenticação, com os seguintes parâmetros:

o   login

o   password

2.     A resposta da requisição feita em 1 terá como resposta uma outra URL. Esta URL representa a localização da instância do sistema a que o usuário pertence, portanto, deve-se fazer uma nova requisição para a URL informada.

Comment: Tente editar a pergunta acrescentando os dados necesários na segunda requisição, que fica mais fácil. Acrescente o que você já tem pronto, (menos os dados particulares, claro), que fica muito mais fácil pra visualizar e eu ou outra pessoa te ajudar. É muito importante o formato dessa segunda requisição, pois o problema parece estar aí.

Comment: @IgorRonner então acho que é só extrair o token e passar corretamente na versão anterior, pois o 401 indica que o endereço estava correto. Porém, sem a documentação correta da API, não saberia como ajudar.

Comment: Mas eu devo colocar a URL completa com o token para a requisição? Você viu minha última edição da resposta?

Comment: Fiz alguns testes e percebi que a 2ª requisição na verdade é um get, pois no browser ele retorna 200 OK, mas quando faço essa mesma requisição no APLICATIVO aparece ERROR 404 Not found